# How to register DLL without vsdrfcomselfreg

Tags: dll, com, registry, installation

I am creating a Visual Studio Setup and Deployment project to install a DLL on the target machine. I have tried many configurations and many registry modifications to no avail. I have finally been able to install and register the DLL using vsdrfcomselfreg, but everywhere I look online seems to deem this method incorrect.

What I would like to know is if there are similar results to this method that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A traditional COM DLL will have the following choices in the register property in the IDE:

- vsdrfCOMSelfReg
- vsdrfCOM
- vsdrfCOMRelativePath

See here:

http://www.simple-talk.com/2005/04/25/getting-started-with-setup-projects/

Comment: In that case do I need something done on my end for the DLL to be able to use the vsdrfCOM option? vsdrfCOMSelfReg always seems to work for me, but vsdrfCOM throws a compiler warning stating that it is unable to build registration information for my dll.

Comment: It is a COM issue. For COM components created in Visual C++ using ATL 6.0 you should choose the vsdrfCOMSelfReg option. See [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h793hc1y.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that link. Kinda good to know that it isn't completely my fault.

Comment: Ia there an easy way to figure out how a COM dll was registerd e.g. what clsid?